# Updating JSON element with feature file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, parsing

I want to update value for one of the attribute in JSON file. I am able to update it, if I am passing the attribute name in code. But if I am trying to pass that attribute name in feature file, its creating additional element in JSON file.

Working Code:

```
await (function replaceJSONData(callback) {
        fs.readFile(requestPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            var tempJSON = JSON.parse(data);
            tempJSON. = customer.personalDetails.customerFullName = "Amanda"
            console.log(tempJSON);
        });
    });
```

Fails and create new node element in JSON request:

```
//NOTE: nodeValue_1 is argument coming from feature file which has value as
|nodeValue_1                              |
|customer.personalDetails.customerFullName|

    this.Given(/^I replace (.*) and (.*) for rest service (.*) from (.*)$/, function (nodeValue_1, nodeValue_2, rest_url, filePath, callback) {
    var requestPath = requestDataPath+'\\'+rest_url+'-req.json';
    var currentAccount = fs.readFileSync(runTimeDataPath+'\\'+filePath, 'utf8');
    console.log(nodeValue_1);
    await (function replaceJSONData(callback) {
        fs.readFile(requestPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            var tempJSON = JSON.parse(data);
//This will add new element called as nodeValue_1 in JSON - FAILS
            tempJSON.nodeValue_1 = "Amanda";
            console.log(tempJSON);
        });
    });
});
```

JSON Request to update:

```
{
"customer": {
    "personalDetails": {
        "userTitle": "Mr",
        "customerFullName": "MrSchaumann",
        "dateOfBirth": "1980-05-08",
        "customerSureName": "Baganz"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear about what you are trying to do? do you want to add a new attribute/node? or you want to update the value?

Comment: Hi @jidexl21, I am trying to replace value in existing json element.

Answer (score 1):

Here tempJSON.nodeValue_1 wont work as nodeValue_1 is a variable. Try using

```
tempJSON[nodeValue_1]
```

nodeValue_1 wont resolve to it's value in dot notation, but if you use tempJSON[nodeValue_1] it will get resolved.

So your final code should look like below:

```
//NOTE: nodeValue_1 is argument coming from feature file which has value as
|nodeValue_1                              |
|customer.personalDetails.customerFullName|

this.Given(/^I replace (.*) and (.*) for rest service (.*) from (.*)$/,
function (nodeValue_1, nodeValue_2, rest_url, filePath, callback) {
var requestPath = requestDataPath+'\\'+rest_url+'-req.json';
var currentAccount = fs.readFileSync(runTimeDataPath+'\\'+filePath, 'utf8');
console.log(nodeValue_1);
await (function replaceJSONData(callback) {
    fs.readFile(requestPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        var tempJSON = JSON.parse(data);
        //This will update the value as you expect.
        tempJSON[nodeValue_1] = "Amanda";
        console.log(tempJSON);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: this is not working. A new element is created name as customer.personalDetails.customerFullName with value "Amanda"

Answer (score 0):

Break up your path (nodeValue_1) into an array and apply it sequentially, remove the lastNode in the path and use it for your update.

```
var p = nodeValue_1.split(".");
var lastNode = p.pop(); 
var resultNode = tempJSON;
p.map(function(itm){
    resultNode = resultNode[itm];    
});  
resultNode[lastNode] = "Amanda";
console.log(JSON.stringify(tempJSON));
```

Ultimately your code should be like

```
this.Given(/^I replace (.*) and (.*) for rest service (.*) from (.*)$/, function (nodeValue_1, nodeValue_2, rest_url, filePath, callback) {
    var requestPath = requestDataPath+'\\'+rest_url+'-req.json';
    var currentAccount = fs.readFileSync(runTimeDataPath+'\\'+filePath, 'utf8');
    console.log(nodeValue_1);
    await (function replaceJSONData(callback) {
        fs.readFile(requestPath, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
           var tempJSON = JSON.parse(data);
           var p = nodeValue_1.split(".");
           var lastNode = p.pop(); 
           var resultNode = tempJSON;
           p.map(function(itm){
             resultNode = resultNode[itm];    
          });  
          resultNode[lastNode] = "Amanda";
            console.log(JSON.stringify(tempJSON));
        });
    });
});
```